# Error while setting data from web api as a JSON Object.W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

Tags: java, android, json, api

Code I have for getting the JSON from the API

```
        String url = "https://api.open5e.com/weapons/?format=json";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url.toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject tasksObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
                            for (Iterator<String> it = tasksObject.keys(); it.hasNext();){
                                String taskId = it.next();
                                JSONObject rObj = tasksObject.getJSONObject(taskId);

                                //get rows
                                String name = rObj.getString("name");
                                String weight = rObj.getString("weight");
                                String value = rObj.getString("cost");

                                Log.d(TAG, name);
                                Log.d(TAG, weight);
                                Log.d(TAG, value);

                                //Call setters setting values to correct values
                                lst list = new lst();
                                list.setlstName(name);
                                list.setLstweight(weight);
                                list.setLstValue(value);
                                lists.add(list);
                            }
```

Error I get from the following when I try and open the itemList page, this is where the name, weight and value are stored.

```
D/ITEMLIST: {"count":37,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"name":"Club","slug":"club","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"1 sp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light"]},{"name":"Dagger","slug":"dagger","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"2 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"1 lb.","properties":["finesse","light","thrown (range 20/60)"]},{"name":"Greatclub","slug":"greatclub","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"2 sp","damage_dice":"1d8","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"10 lb.","properties":["two-handed"]},{"name":"Handaxe","slug":"handaxe","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"5 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"slashing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light","thrown (range 20/60)"]},{"name":"Javelin","slug":"javelin","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"5 sp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["thrown (range 30/120)"]},{"name":"Light hammer","slug":"light-hammer","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"2 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light","thrown (range 20/60)"]},{"name":"Mace","slug":"mace","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"5 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"4 lb.","properties":[]},{"name":"Quarterstaff","slug":"quarterstaff","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"2 sp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"4 lb.","properties":["versatile (1d8)"]},{"name":"Sickle","slug":"sickle","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"1 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"slashing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light"]},{"name":"Spear","slug":"spear","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"1 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"3 lb.","properties":["thrown (range 20/60)","versatile (1d8)"]},{"name":"Crossbow, light","slug":"crossbow-light","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"25 gp","damage_dice":"1d8","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"5 lb.","properties":["ammunition (range 80/320)","loading","two-handed"]},{"name":"Dart","slug":"dart","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"5 cp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"1/4 lb.","properties":["finesse","thrown (range 20/60)"]},{"name":"Shortbow","slug":"shortbow","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http://open5e.com/legal","cost":"25 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"Club","slug":"club","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"1 sp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light"]},{"name":"Dagger","slug":"dagger","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"2 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"1 lb.","properties":["finesse","light","thrown (range 20\/60)"]},{"name":"Greatclub","slug":"greatclub","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"2 sp","damage_dice":"1d8","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"10 lb.","properties":["two-handed"]},{"name":"Handaxe","slug":"handaxe","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"5 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"slashing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light","thrown (range 20\/60)"]},{"name":"Javelin","slug":"javelin","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"5 sp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["thrown (range 30\/120)"]},{"name":"Light hammer","slug":"light-hammer","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"2 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light","thrown (range 20\/60)"]},{"name":"Mace","slug":"mace","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"5 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"4 lb.","properties":[]},{"name":"Quarterstaff","slug":"quarterstaff","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"2 sp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"bludgeoning","weight":"4 lb.","properties":["versatile (1d8)"]},{"name":"Sickle","slug":"sickle","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"1 gp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"slashing","weight":"2 lb.","properties":["light"]},{"name":"Spear","slug":"spear","category":"Simple Melee Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"1 gp","damage_dice":"1d6","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"3 lb.","properties":["thrown (range 20\/60)","versatile (1d8)"]},{"name":"Crossbow, light","slug":"crossbow-light","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"25 gp","damage_dice":"1d8","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"5 lb.","properties":["ammunition (range 80\/320)","loading","two-handed"]},{"name":"Dart","slug":"dart","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"5 cp","damage_dice":"1d4","damage_type":"piercing","weight":"1\/4 lb.","properties":["finesse","thrown (range 20\/60)"]},{"name":"Shortbow","slug":"shortbow","category":"Simple Ranged Weapons","document__slug":"wotc-srd","document__title":"Systems Reference Document","document__license_url":"http:\/\/open5e.com\/legal","cost":"25 gp"
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:624)
        at com.example.a5ENotes.itemlist$1.onResponse(itemlist.java:119)
        at com.example.a5ENotes.itemlist$1.onResponse(itemlist.java:112)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I console logged the response and that seems to be fine, it seems to break as soon as I get to. JSONObject tasksObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");

So I thought maybe it was a problem with the API cause it pulls half of it, but I put the JSON from https://api.open5e.com/weapons/ into a validator and it was fine. Concluding that I'm just probably doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

"results" is JSONArray and not JSONObject. You would have to do something like this, to access results:

```
try
{
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
  for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
  {
     JSONObject rObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     String name = rObj.getString("name");
     String weight = rObj.getString("weight");
     String value = rObj.getString("cost");
  }
}
```